# Helping filter what really matters

Tags: phd

So the other day I received an email from the department head stating:

1. Please list your highest degree.
2. Please list any professional development activities that you’ve done in the last 5 years.

He emphasized that it was for reviewing the department as a whole.

Now, I'm an adjunct so the same rules don't apply to me as the full time faculty, but it did help me focus a little bit. I thought about how my inbox is always full with professional development activities, but I don't think any of it could be listed in a cv.

Facebook? Really? But I do subscribe to 2 different Facebook groups in my area of expertise. I have since unsubscribed from them both.

Is reading the Wall Street Journal something that I can claim as a professional development activity? What about the myriad of other subscriptions? Discarded.

What should a person focus on in order to advance their career as a teacher? Is getting a PhD the bar that must be hurdled before anything else?

Here is my question: How should I approach my department chair and say that I would like to beef up my Curriculum Vitae, with the school's help?

Comment: Directly, as if he were a real live flesh-and-blood human being.

Comment: Note: just because your department head is asking about it doesn't mean it's something you would put in your CV. It might be useful for the department in developing professional development activities or for talking about how people in the department have access to professional development, but that doesn't mean it belongs on an individual's CV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a pretty big topic and here are some cluttered and clustered thoughts:

> How should I approach my department chair and say that I would like to
>   beef up my Curriculum Vitae, with the school's help?

First, I would not advise going in bare hand. For i) most deans don't really know how to manage adjunct, ii) you may get advice that is not exactly up your alley but feel politically you should say yes. Instead, go with a plan.

It's hard to develop without a goal. So, think what do you want to achieve as a faculty member. And there are many things, just to name a few:

**Teaching-related:** pedagogical training (from general enhancement to how to deal with special students), use of new teaching technology or platform, (re)design of curriculum, organizing of local/foreign workshop.

**Research-related:** grantsmanship, training in new technology or skills, management, writing and publication.

**More general:** professional conferences, network building, public relationship/press.

If you're absolutely clueless, download their promotion package template and see what criteria are considered during promotion. While you are unlikely not in the promotion track, the contents will be helpful.

Pick 1-3 for next year. Then, before your next annual review (if you don't have one, schedule a meeting), frame them as:

> In the next (6 months/ 12 months), I would like to achieve _______ (a goal). This would bring the benefits of _______ (at least one win-win benefit). In order to do that I'd like to know if I can _______ (your ask).

For example: *"In the next 12 months I'd like to implement flipped classroom format in the course XY111. This would be a timely response to our university 2030 Teaching Goals announced last month. In order to do that I'd like to attend this 3-day workshop in DC. I'd like to see if the department can allocate some stipend for this development activity."*

Simply put, just follow the SMART: Specific, Measurable, Attainable, Relevant, and Time specific.

---

For routine development, make sure to familiarize yourself with faculty benefit: tuition remission, access to library services, discount to other academic activities, etc. Milk that affiliation.

---

Think win-win or who would benefit other than you when justifying your arguments. For instance:

> Is reading the Wall Street Journal something that I can claim as a
>   professional development activity?

to that I would say no because staying on top of the field is more of a routine. But I would say yes to:

> Developed 2 teaching cases using op-ed from Wall Street Journal and
>   successfully applied them in course XY111. (See class reflection and
>   evaluation in appendix.)

because in this case we used what we know to actively improve the quality or variety of teaching methods, while we get to experience using case teaching as a teaching development.

If these seem all very large and confusing I'd suggest talking to some other faculty members who has not vested interest in this matter.